# Dnf not working after deleting libraries

Tags: libraries, dnf, ncurses

I am using Fedora 37 and have Linux kernel: `6.1.7-200.fc37.x86_64`.

While trying to replace some libraries (`libncurses.so.5`) for STMCubeIDE I have deleted some files in `/usr/lib/libncurses*`. Now, when I try to use anything with dnf I get the following message:

```bash
$ sudo dnf update
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/dnf", line 61, in <module>
    from dnf.cli import main
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/dnf/cli/__init__.py", line 30, in <module>
    from dnf.cli.cli import Cli  # :api
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/dnf/cli/cli.py", line 44, in <module>
    from . import output
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/dnf/cli/output.py", line 42, in <module>
    import dnf.cli.progress
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/dnf/cli/progress.py", line 19, in <module>
    from dnf.cli.term import _term_width
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/dnf/cli/term.py", line 21, in <module>
    import curses
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.11/curses/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from _curses import *
ImportError: libncursesw.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I would like to know if there is an easy way to just repair dnf or this specific problem.

Comment: Just to stress this: whyever you were deleting system libraries, that is always a bad idea.

Comment: I don't know if you downvoted my post or not, but whoever did: I don't see how this post would not follow stackexcange rules. If I did a mistake, it doesn't make any sense for you to downvote the post. I know it wasn't reasonable for me to delete those files, but we are here to help each other and giving downvote to post just because you think I don't know how to use a computer is ignorant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deleting system files is almost always a terrible idea.

You should restore the files from a backup. If you don't have a backup, do a clean install of Fedora 37 on a VM and copy the deleted files from there.

Comment: I took a copy from friend's same distro and it works now.